# Page refreshes when I click Register

Tags: javascript, html, refresh

I am working on an RPG game, I'm almost done, but this problem occurs. For some reason when I click 'Register' page refreshes..? I copied this register code by the way, so that could be the problem?

```
<input type='hidden' name='referer' value=''>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" class="button"/>
```

This is the code, please suggest.

Comment: make you code clear please

Comment: You need to Improve your post for more clarity

Comment: Maybe you should show us the full form.  If you don't know how to make an HTML form, follow a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Your second input type is submit, which makes the form submit all entered data into the specified "action" page. If you are interested in reading more look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp). By default, the action page just submits to the current page (I think). So it seems to just reload.

Also, your code is invalid, the proper syntax would have brackets `<>` around the inputs; like this and "hidden" is not a valid type

```
<input type='hidden' name='referer' value=''> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" class="button"/>
```